# Reference Api in c#

Tags: c#, swagger, blazor

I created an api for CRUD operations on Db and then through Swagger Editor I generated a Client Api file.

On my project I made the reference to the client file (Let's suppose it is called swagFile) previously generated.

if I type "swagFile" in my project blazor intellisense shows me the various methods of my api,
but they don't work because I have to register a service in Startup.cs first.

i have no idea how to initialize the service and start using my api's methods. and I don't know if you need to do the other steps first.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: A pretty good tutorial is wirrten in the documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Are you aware that Blazor doesn't really need Swagger?  You can easily share a DLL with DTO classes.

Comment: How do you mean, @HenkHolterman ? This sounds like the Blazor app is a WA one and the swagger is helping generate the client stub

Comment: I didn't know, I'll take a look thanks @HenkHolterman

Comment: @CaiusJard - It does add some value but also a lot of complexity. In a small/mid-sized project I wouldn't use it, Blazor has an attractive alternative built-in.

Answer (score 1):

As [Michael Mairegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2964291/michael-mairegger) mentioned in his comment, there is a [good description provided by Microsoft.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

The most important part is that you have added a minimum configuration in `Startup.cs` like the following example (assuming it is using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen`):

Define at class level

```
const string SwaggerTitle = "My.Api"; // name of your project
const string SwaggerVersion = "v1";
```

Configure the services as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{   
    // services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
    services.AddControllers();

    // Register the Swagger generator
    // without authentication/authorization, this would be just: services.AddSwaggerGen();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        //Defines a document for one specific version, in the future we could have multiple documents depending on api versioning
        options.SwaggerDoc(SwaggerVersion, new OpenApiInfo { Title = SwaggerTitle, Version = SwaggerVersion });
        
        // This will add XML comments to Swagger 
        // (enable in Build/Output of the API project properties the option "XML documentation file for all configurations")  
        options.IncludeXmlComments(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{SwaggerTitle}.xml"));            
    });
}
```

And the Configure method should be like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
        //c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/v1/swagger.json";
    });

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
    // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", $"My API {SwaggerVersion}");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });

    app.UseRouting();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

There are much more options available, as described in the link above, but that'll be the starting point. Try it with that first, and then experiment with further settings from the article.

Note that you need to set up your project's properties to make the compiler generate an `.XML` file containing your XML comments (from the controller source code), which is then being used by Swagger.

In Visual Studio 2022, you can find it here in the project properties (Build / Output):
[image: XML File Gen]

**Important:**

- Make sure the option "Generate a file containing API documentation" (Documentation file) is enabled.
- "InsertYourProjectPath": Use the base path for your project here. Usually, once you enabled XML file creation, the path suggested is already the right one - you just need to change the name of the XML file just as you named it in `SwaggerTitle` appended with `.xml`. If you're not sure, place a breakpoint inside `.AddSwaggerGen` and inspect `AppContext.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: I think this is the server part, the OP had that down.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - But he also wrote: "... they don't work because I have to register a service in Startup.cs first. I have no idea how to initialize the service and start using my api's methods." This is the part I answered.

Comment: @account italianu - is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @Matt yes and no, I followed the doc, when I went to call api without using the reference, and in Startup.cs I added:                                                                                                                                                                - services.AddHttpClient <IProductService, ProductService> (client =>
   {
                 client.BaseAddress = new Uri ("http: // localhost: 36942 /");
    });        //      now that I am using the reference to the file created by Swagger Editor, do I follow the same procedure?

Comment: @account italianu - I made the configuration more explicit, so it is easier for you to add more configuration if needed.